# spark dataframe - get statistical info from past rows when a condition is met

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider the data displayed below

| Date | Timestamp | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-01 05:30:30 | 0.5 | -2 | Null |
| 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-01 10:40:30 | 1 | -1 | Null |
| 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-01 10:50:30 | 1.5 | 1 | 1 |
| 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-01 23:00:30 | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 2019-01-02 | 2019-01-02 02:30:30 | 0 | 10 | 1 |
| 2019-01-02 | 2019-01-02 05:40:30 | 3 | -5 | Null |
| 2019-01-02 | 2019-01-02 21:50:30 | 5 | -10 | 1 |

1. The moment the column C is not null, I want to obtain the min and avg values for the past rows up to this moment.
2. If the the element in column C is not null but the past value was also not null, just disregard that value.
3. since there is a timestamp, I would like to get the time difference in minutes up to the appearance of non-null elements in column C

To exemplify, the desired result for the table above is the following table:

| C | min(A) | avg(A) | min(B) | avg(B) | delta(TimeStamp) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.5 | 1 | -2 | -0.666 | 320 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | -10 | -7.5 | 970 |

Explaining the first row of the desired table.

- the avg(A) and avg(B) are equal to (0.5+1+1.5)/3 and (-2-1+1)/3, respectively.
- when the first non-null element appears in column C, the time difference is 05:30:00, which is equal to 320 min.

I am kinda clueless on how to do it when working with a spark dataframe.